# Can't join third table in php/mysql to get user name

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a join that I have working perfectly. However, I need to join to a third table called wp_users so I can access the user display name. When I add  a second join I keep getting all sorts of errors depending on what I try so I'm turning for help.

The third table, wp_users has two columns:
wp_users.ID,
wp_users.display_name

Here is the code before I add the second join code so I can get the display name for the results ID

```
//Works, but I need to join to wp_users on wp_users.ID to get display_name

$results = $dbh->prepare("select 
stories.ID,
stories.SID,
stories.story_name,
stories.category,
points.ID,
points.PID,
FROM stories
JOIN points ON stories.SID=points.SID
JOIN stories ON wp_users.ID=points.ID
where (points.ID = $user_ID) and (PID = 1)");
$results->execute();
```

Comment: what is your error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `stories` to `wp_users`

```
JOIN stories ON wp_users.ID=points.ID
```

to

```
JOIN wp_users ON wp_users.ID=points.ID

$results = $dbh->prepare("select 
stories.ID,
stories.SID,
stories.story_name,
stories.category,
points.ID,
points.PID,
FROM stories
JOIN points ON stories.SID=points.SID
JOIN wp_users ON wp_users.ID=points.ID
where (points.ID = $user_ID) and (PID = 1)");
$results->execute();
```

Comment: I figured it out, but your way looks good too, so I'll accept. I did: JOIN wp_users ON stories.ID=wp_users.ID

Comment: did my answer help to  you?